# "Stream" class not defined when not using "using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;"

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to convert an image source from a Xamarin ImageButton control to a SkiaSharp bitmap. I've found that the Stream class is not defined when I attempt to use it without the using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific; namespace import. However, when I do include this namespace, all of my controls start to get "name between" errors.

I've tried removing the using statement, but the error persists. I'm not sure why the Stream class is only available when using this namespace, and why it's causing issues with my controls.

code:

```
// assuming that b is my ImageButton

using (var stream = b.Source.Stream)
{
    SKBitmap bitmap2 = new SKBitmap((int)b.Width, (int)b.Height);
    bitmap2.Decode(stream);
}
```

Comment: You have to cast to StreamImageSource to use the Stream property

Comment: also, if you have conflicting namespace errors, there are much easier ways to solve them

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to convert an image source from a Xamarin ImageButton
> control to a SkiaSharp bitmap.

Unfortunately it can not convert Source from ImageButton or Image to bitmap.

But you can get a Bitmap from Resource, refer to the doc: [Loading a Bitmap Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/bitmaps#loading-a-bitmap-resource).